# Why are kernel log messages in the syslog file (or those redirected to terminal) exactly one 'message' behind?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, syslog

I wrote a simple hello-world module on Ubuntu 10.04 machine. When loading and unloading the module, printk should log messages from the following hello_world and bye_world functions.

```
static int hello_world()
{
        printk(KERN_INFO "Hello, beautiful world");
        return 0;
}

static void bye_world()
{
        printk(KERN_INFO "Good-bye kernel uncle");
}

module_init(hello_world);
module_exit(bye_world);
```

However, when actually inserting and removing the hello.ko module, I see that the message printed on the terminal (I redirected it to the current terminal) is exactly one message behind.

> ```
> # rmmod hello.ko
> # Jul  8 16:34:02 panchavati kernel: [64599.954113] Hello, beautiful world
>
> # insmod hello.ko
> # Jul  8 16:34:57 panchavati kernel: [65456.367422] Good-bye kernel uncle
> ```

From dmesg output, I can see the next message entry (corresponding to insmod) has been already logged, just that it is not being printed yet.

> ```
> chanakya@panchavati:~$ dmesg | tail -2
> [65456.367422] Good-bye kernel uncle
> [65511.198299] Hello, beautiful world
> ```

The entry `[65511.198299]` is there in the kernel log, but only the previous entry `[65456.367422] Good-bye kernel uncle` was printed. Why is it so?

I earlier thought that ['-' specifier](http://linux.die.net/man/8/syslogd) used in /etc/syslog.conf might have to do something with this (it prevents synchronization after every write), but removing it didn't work either.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using `tailf` (or `tail -f`)? It will print out the messages as they arrive. For example:

```
    tailf /var/log/messages
```

Answer (score 1):

Try ending your strings with a newline ("\n").